# Enum member as a default value on signature

Tags: python, enums, mutable

I know that assign a mutable object as a default value on function is bad practice.

Something like:

```
def foo(a = []):
   pass
```

My question is assign a Enum member is also a bad practice?

Something like:

```
Class SomeEnum(Enum)
   ENUM_KEY = SomeClass()

def foo(a = SomeEnum.ENUM_KEY)
    pass
```

Comment: `SomeEnum.ENUM_KEY` is an instance of `SomeEnum`, which is mutable. `SomeEnum.ENUM_KEY.value` (`SomeClass()`) is (generally speaking) also mutable. By mutability, which object do you mean exactly? More concretely, for example, does your problem still exist if `SomeClass = int`? By the way, the second code snippet is not a valid python code. Please check for the grammar.

Comment: It doesn't matter what the type of the default argument is. What matters is if the function mutates it without being aware that *all* future calls to the function will see the mutation.

Comment: If `foo` treats `a` as an immutable value, there is no problem with using `[]` as the default argument value for `a`.

Answer (score 0):

Using an enum member as a default parameter is (usually) fine.

The `value` of an enum member is usually constant (such as `1`, `debug`, or `Monday`), but it is possible to use a mutable value, such as an empty list.  If you are going to mutate the value of the enum in the function, then you have the same risks as directly using a mutable default.

Comment: Your second paragraph (which is correct) contradicts your first sentence. It *might* be OK to use an `enum` member as a default argument, but for the same reasons that an arbitrary value of *any* type might be OK.

Comment: @chepner: Good point, corrected first sentence.